# Telerik RadEditor's ImageManager broken, even no css applied

Tags: telerik, image-editor

I'm using Tererik:RadEditor in asp.net. When I click ImageManger it is shown totally broken. I have not applied any CSS to the page or any control.

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens exactly because you didn't apply Telerik Css file to your control. 
To fix this, you need to add css file for editor control to your page. you can do it in markup or design mode by selecting skin.

If you're going to inspect your code, you should see 404 errors. Do you see them?

Comment: @hotcoder, you will have to register telerik in webconfig, then try to add using telerik stylesheet manager as described here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager.html or you can try to create your project from scratch and use Telerik website as a template, it should work out of the box.

Comment: I had to add   <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadStyleSheetManager>

Answer (score 1):

Hi this issue comes because of some missing handlers. Please add the following to your handlers in Web.config file to fix the above issue.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false" />
  <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
     <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This should fix the issue.